# Is Xamarin Forms CollectionView working on macOS?

Tags: macos, xamarin.forms

I've migrated a settings page from Xamarin Forms ListView to CollectionView. All is working on iOS, but nothing is rendered on macOS.

I downgraded Xamarin Forms to 4.7 and pushed it all of the way up to the current preview of 5.0.0.1829-pre6. I've searched the source on git, and I can't even find a renderer for CollectionView. My searches on the web come back with nothing specific.

Is CollectionView supported on macOS? If not, what is the roadmap for support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of the current production release (4.8.X), 'CollectionView' is not supported on macOS, it is supported on the following platforms:

- iOS
- Android
- UWP

There is no timeline for official support but I would hope it would become available in 5.X since that version will go into LTS when MAUI takes over. I checked the [Xamarin GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms) repo and couldn't find an [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13289) so I raised one for macOS support for `CollectionView`. Going to the repository is the best way to keep updated, if you show your support they are more likely to do the work

Comment: I'm running 5.0.0.1829-pre6, and there's no support there. I agree...lack of platform support for CollectionView on macOS has forced me to stay with my handrolled Repeater library control.

Comment: Yes its very frustrating, I'm tackling the issue by putting lots of conditionals into my xaml to use a `ListView` on mac where I use a `CollectionView` everywhere else.

Comment: That's a wise approach, as SwipeView isn't implemented on macOS either, but ListView offers its own slider support. I'd probably go the macOS renderer route myself, but your conditional approach is clear and valid.